# businessHours en Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

que tal? Estoy usando FullCalendar y tengo una duda al usar la funcion "businessHours". ¿Como puedo hacer para cambiar los horarios laborales de un dia en especifico? Por ejemplo, quisiera que el dia 28/01 tenga otros horarios laborales, diferentes a los implementados en "businessHours", siendo que de 7:40pm a 10pm quede habilitado para crear eventos. Y el resto de los dias quede como esta.

[image: Aca adjunto la imagen de muestra]

Answer (score 0):

Puede dividir su declaración de horas hábiles en partes, en una matriz de objetos, para un control adicional:

```js
businessHours: [ // specify an array instead
  {
    daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3 ], // Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
    startTime: '08:00', // 8am
    endTime: '18:00' // 6pm
  },
  {
    daysOfWeek: [ 4, 5 ], // Thursday, Friday
    startTime: '10:00', // 10am
    endTime: '16:00' // 4pm
  }
]
```